# How come opencv is creating 2 windows?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, tk-toolkit

Found code from Github (https://github.com/atulapra/Emotion-detection) for emotion detection. I want to make some changes in it and want to combine with Tkinter for an easy user interaction. Something like this shown in image below.
[image]
Here I wrote some code for tk window:

```
win = Tk()
win.title('EMOTIBOT')
win.config(background = "#D9D9D9")
win.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

#frame1 for webcamera
frame1 = Frame(win, width=600, bg="black",height=300, padx=10, pady=10,highlightbackground="grey", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=5)
frame1.pack(side=LEFT ,fill=Y,padx=10, pady=10)
```

Here I made some changes in the original code:

```
if mode == "display":
    model.load_weights('model.h5')

    # prevents openCL usage and unnecessary logging messages
    cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)

    # dictionary which assigns each label an emotion (alphabetical order)
    emotion_dict = {0: "Angry", 1: "Disgusted", 2: "Fearful", 3: "Happy", 4: "Neutral", 5: "Sad", 6: "Surprised"}

    # start the webcam feed
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def show_frame():
        _, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        #cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)

        #while True:
        facecasc = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = facecasc.detectMultiScale(cv2image,scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)

        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y-50), (x+w, y+h+10), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            cropped_img = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(cv2.resize(roi_gray, (48, 48)), -1), 0)
            prediction = model.predict(cropped_img)
            maxindex = int(np.argmax(prediction))
            cv2.putText(frame, emotion_dict[maxindex], (x+20, y-60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow('Video', cv2.resize(frame,(1600,960),interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC))

        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        lmain.after(10, show_frame) 

    #Capture video frames
    lmain = Label(frame1)
    lmain.grid(row=0, column=0)

    show_frame()  #Display 2
    win.mainloop()
```

This is opening 2 windows. The first window, Tk window with no rectangles on detected emotions. The second window is showing rectangles on detected emotions. Why the first tk window is not showing rectangles on faces? 
[image]

if you need my script file it's here. (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m7tLFxHF_hO0VLVb8FgAf-4lJKMxFLxA/view?usp=sharing)

I'm new to both OpenCV and Tk. Please help me.

Comment: I think it's `cv2.imshow` that opens the second window, can you try to remove that line?

Comment: And you are creating the frame for the tk window starting from `cv2image`, you should use `frame` instead

Comment: @BlackBear I removed the `cv2.imshow ` and it does solve my error. Thank you. But the 
 cam feed in main Tk window is not detecting the emotions.

Comment: Try `img = Image.fromarray(frame)`

Comment: @BlackBear can you elaborate on where to use `frame`. Thanks.

Comment: @BlackBear I tried `img = Image.fromarray(frame)` and it worked. But the colours are separated and is making me look like a ghost. Also, emotions are detected only when I move away from camera. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "colors are separated". For the face detection problem, you should refer to facecasc's documentation

Comment: @BlackBear My face has turned blue/ violet. My black T-shirt has turned red.

Comment: `img = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA))` perhaps?

Comment: @BlackBear Thank you so much. It solved my problem. I was trying this whole day. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize our discussion into an answer [that can be accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235):

1. Remove `cv2.imshow` to get rid of the second window
2. Use `img = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA))` to display the frame with the detected face with the right colors.